# ROS2_Iron - Camera calibration file (camera_info.yaml) not loaded by usb_cam camera driver

Tags: ros2, calibration, usb-cam, ros-iron

Running ROS2 Iron with the usb_cam driver.

```
I ran the calibration script as suggested by the wiki and saved the yaml file to
/opt/ros/iron/share/usb_cam/config/camera_info.yaml
```

Now when I go to run the driver to get the corrected images to a topic (with the command

```
ros2 run usb_cam usb_cam_node_exe --ros-args --params-file /opt/ros/iron/share/usb_cam/config/params.yaml --remap image_raw:=image
```

), the calibration is not applied. Params.yaml content down here:

```
/**:
    ros__parameters:
      video_device: "/dev/video0"
      framerate: 15.0
      io_method: "mmap"
      frame_id: "camera"
      pixel_format: "mjpeg2rgb"  # see usb_cam/supported_formats for list of supported formats
      av_device_format: "YUV422P"
      image_width: 1600
      image_height: 1200
      camera_name: "default_cam"
      camera_info_url: "file:///opt/ros/iron/share/usb_cam/config/camera_info.yaml"
     # camera_info_url: "package://usb_cam/config/camera_info.yaml"
      brightness: -1
      contrast: -1
      saturation: -1
      sharpness: -1
      gain: -1
      auto_white_balance: false
      autoexposure: false
      autofocus: false
      focus: -1
```

All the other parameters are applied, as you can see down here

```
[INFO] [1709827622.870491090] [usb_cam]: camera_name value: default_cam
[WARN] [1709827622.870600440] [usb_cam]: framerate: 15.000000
[INFO] [1709827622.872847952] [usb_cam]: camera calibration URL: file:///opt/ros/iron/share/usb_cam/config/camera_info.yaml
[INFO] [1709827622.986680707] [usb_cam]: Starting 'default_cam' (/dev/video0) at 1600x1200 via mmap (mjpeg2rgb) at 15 FPS
This device supports the following formats:
    Motion-JPEG 1600 x 1200 (15 Hz)
    Motion-JPEG 1600 x 1200 (15 Hz)
    Motion-JPEG 2592 x 1944 (15 Hz)
    Motion-JPEG 2048 x 1536 (15 Hz)
    Motion-JPEG 1920 x 1080 (30 Hz)
    Motion-JPEG 1280 x 1024 (15 Hz)
    Motion-JPEG 1280 x 720 (30 Hz)
    Motion-JPEG 1024 x 768 (30 Hz)
    Motion-JPEG 800 x 600 (30 Hz)
    Motion-JPEG 640 x 480 (30 Hz)
    Motion-JPEG 1600 x 1200 (15 Hz)
    Motion-JPEG 1600 x 1200 (15 Hz)
    YUYV 4:2:2 1600 x 1200 (5 Hz)
    YUYV 4:2:2 1600 x 1200 (5 Hz)
    YUYV 4:2:2 2592 x 1944 (3 Hz)
    YUYV 4:2:2 2048 x 1536 (4 Hz)
    YUYV 4:2:2 1920 x 1080 (5 Hz)
    YUYV 4:2:2 1280 x 1024 (9 Hz)
    YUYV 4:2:2 1280 x 720 (5 Hz)
    YUYV 4:2:2 1024 x 768 (10 Hz)
    YUYV 4:2:2 800 x 600 (20 Hz)
    YUYV 4:2:2 640 x 480 (30 Hz)
    YUYV 4:2:2 1600 x 1200 (5 Hz)
    YUYV 4:2:2 1600 x 1200 (5 Hz)
[INFO] [1709827623.026446424] [usb_cam]: Setting 'white_balance' to 4000
unknown control 'white_balance_temperature_auto'

white_balance_temperature: Permission denied
VIDIOC_S_CTRL: failed: Permission denied

[INFO] [1709827623.042949174] [usb_cam]: Setting 'exposure_auto' to 1
[INFO] [1709827623.043033954] [usb_cam]: Setting 'exposure' to 100
unknown control 'exposure_auto'

unknown control 'exposure_absolute'

[INFO] [1709827623.058877997] [usb_cam]: Setting 'focus_auto' to 0
unknown control 'focus_auto'

[INFO] [1709827623.372774575] [usb_cam]: Timer triggering every 66 ms
```

but the image is not corrected. I tested this with foxglove and got this result
[image]

which means that the calibration is correct, just isn’t being applied.
What am I doing wrong in the usb_cam launch command?